# Vestacp: Ftp not working

Tags: ftp, vesta

I have a problem. When I try to connect with ftp it gives this error.

```
/etc/vsftpd.conf 

anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
anon_umask=022
anon_upload_enable=NO
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=NO
tcp_wrappers=YES
force_dot_files=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
seccomp_sandbox=NO
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=12000
pasv_max_port=12100
max_per_ip=10
max_clients=100
use_localtime=YES
pasv_address='35.195.69.80'
```

FTP Output

```
Status: Connecting to 35.233.4.11:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   500 OOPS: invalid pasv_address
Command:    PORT 192,168,1,34,199,3
Response:   500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Error:  Connection closed by server
```

FTP connect config field

```
host => packages.pastheme.com
Username => *****
Pass => *****
```

What I've done is I can not handle this problem. I reset the VEST after this operation but the result is the same again. my operating system ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be related to firewall issues: The command port (21) is open for business, but the PASSIVE transfer mode ports are blocked. A nice explaination can be found [here](https://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/80512/active-v-s-passive-ftp-simplified)

In my case, the server was behind an extra 'firewall layer' provided by the ISP (e.g. security groups in AWS). So first observe the the min- and max port for passive transfer mode in Vesta CP:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=12100
pasv_min_port=12000
```

Next, make sure you open this range for service:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

server firewall don't allow to send data to client, let it to be connected by below code:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

check if new users path is registered in /etc/shells.

```
nano /etc/shells
```

and I easily added this line if there isn't:

```
/usr/sbin/nologin
```

after all restart related services to be sure:

```
service iptables restart
service vsftpd restart
```